# How to check if a post exist?

Tags: loop

I am trying to create a new post on the first entry to a contest, then updating that existing entry upon subsequent entries, so I can have one post per entry, but allow multiple entries.

The Problem is that if you enter the contest (see link below), it will create a new post (it works). Then, if you refresh the page, it will say you need to wait X minutes (in this case it's 5 minutes) before you can enter again (it works).

But, if you go back to the entry page, and enter again with the same email and same zip, or same email and different zip, it will sometimes do the right thing and update the post entry, but sometimes it creates a new entry (new post) instead of updating the existing one.

I need help to make it do the right thing. To update the entry if it exists and to create a new one if it doesn't exist.

The Code:

```
// SYSTEM VARS

$currentTime    = time();
$entryCode      = md5($entryEmail);

// ENTRY DATA
$entryEmail = sanitize_email($_POST['entryEmail']);
$entryZip   = sanitize_text_field($_POST['entryZip']);
$entryIP    = $_POST['entryIP'];



// CREATE ENTRY


function createEntry($cee, $cez, $ceip, $cec) {

$newEntry = wp_insert_post(

        array(
            'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
            'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
            'post_author'       =>  '1',
            'post_title'        =>  $cee,
            'post_status'       =>  'publish',
            'post_type'         =>  'custom_type_entries'
        )
    );

wp_insert_post($newEntry);

update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryCode', $cec, true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryIP', $ceip, true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryZip', $cez, true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryTime', time(), true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryLast', time(), true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryNumber', '1', true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryWinner', '0', true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryWinnerTime', '0', true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryEmail', $cee, true);
update_post_meta($newEntry, 'entryEmailSubscribe', '0', true);
}

function writeEntry($we) {

        $entryFile  = "entries.txt";
        $dataFile   = fopen($entryFile, 'a');
        $entryData  = $we . "\n";
        fwrite($dataFile, $entryData);
        fclose($dataFile);

}


function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}


// CHECK TO SEE IF ALREADY ENTERED
$loop = new WP_Query( 

                array( 
                    'post_type'         => 'custom_type_entries', 
                    'posts_per_page'    => '-1' )
            );


while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

    $postID             = $post->ID;
    $entry              = get_post_meta($postID, 'entryEmail', true);
    $day                = "300";
    $entryTime          = get_post_meta($postID, 'entryTime', true);
    $entryLastTime      = get_post_meta($postID, 'entryLast', true);
    $entryCheckIP       = get_post_meta($postID, 'entryIP', true);
    $entryCheckTime     = $currentTime - $entryTime;
    $entryCheckLastTime = $currentTime - $entryLastTime;

    if ($entry == $entryEmail) {



            // IF LESS THAN 24 HOURS SINCE FIRST ENTRY--
            if ($entryCheckTime <= $day) {

                $entryNext = $day - $entryCheckTime;

                echo "Time to Second Entry: " . secondsToTime($entryNext);
                get_footer();
                exit;


            }

            if ($entryCheckTime >= $day) {

                // IF LESS THAN 24 HOURS SINCE LAST ENTRY--
                if ($entryCheckLastTime <= $day) {

                    $entryNext = $day - $entryCheckLastTime;

                    echo "Time to Next Entry: " . secondsToTime($entryNext);
                    get_footer();
                    exit;


                }

                // IF MORE THAN 24 HOURS SINCE LAST ENTRY--
                elseif ($entryCheckLastTime >= $day) {

                    // UPDATE ENTRY COUNTER
                    $entryNumber = get_post_meta($postID, 'entryNumber', true);
                    $entryNumber++;
                    update_post_meta($postID, 'entryNumber', $entryNumber);

                    // UPDATE ENTRY TIME
                    update_post_meta($postID, 'entryLast', $currentTime);

                    // WRITE ENTRY TO FILE
                    writeEntry($entryEmail);

                    // WRAP IY UP YO..
                    echo "Entry Updated!";
                    get_footer();
                    exit;
                }       
            }

    }

    else {

        // CREATE ENTRY
        createEntry($entryEmail, $entryZip, $entryIP, $entryCode);

        // WRITE ENTRY EMAIL TO FILE
        writeEntry($entryEmail);

        // WRAP IT UP YO..
        echo "New Entry!";
        get_footer();
        exit;

    }

endwhile; 

wp_reset_query();
```

Live Example:

Submit Form: [weeklyweedbox.com/win](http://weeklyweedbox.com/win)

Comment: `wp_reset_query` should only be used to clean up after `query_posts` calls, and you should never be using `query_posts`, perhaps you meant to use `wp_reset_postdata`? I'd also advise against storing the entry data as a text file, you already have a custom post type that can store that data, file writes will only slow down the page

Answer (score 1):

You want to rethink this code... to begin with, as the number of entries grow, looping them all is a bad idea. Consider adding a `meta_query` argument to the `WP_Query` so you are not looping through every single entry in the future, but limiting the database retrieval instead.

Mainly you want to get rid of the last `else{}` wrapper and move the code inside of it to *outside* of the `while` loop completely, or you will be creating a *lot* of false entries. You may not have noticed if you are only testing one email address. This may also mean adding another condition to only trigger all of this when a form has actually been submitted (eg. `if (isset($_POST['entryEmail')) {` ... (just above `$loop`)

There are also some other bugs going on..!

...right at the top you need to move `$entryCode` down to *after* `$entryEmail` is defined...

...inside `createEntry` you should be using `add_post_meta` - not `update_post_meta` which only works if the meta value already exists...

...no big deal but `$day` should be set as 300 not "300", an integer not string...

What to learn from this? Go over the logic of your code a few more times before expecting it to work. You will be unlikely to get this kind of detailed response in future (you got lucky) - as code review is not the purpose of a Q&A site. Instead you would generally have to narrow down to a specific bug that you cannot figure out having attempted far more thoroughly to work it out yourself - and this would show in the way you ask the question.